# Integrating Flattr into a chatbot

Tags: flattr

I have a chatbot running on a site and I'd like to be able to integrate flattr into it.  It's built in Node and has no front-end,  it just uses an API to interact with the site.

I'd like to be able to do something like this

**note**: all commands for the bot begin with "!"
`!flattr  @username` to flattr a user

I understand this would mean people who want to either receive or give flattr would have to create accounts

Just looking for some guidance as to how to start this.

Here's what I'm thinking I need to:

Create an application, get Client ID and Secret, go through Oauth flow and get Bearer token.  Including the scope for `flattr thing` in this process

How long are your tokens set to expire? Should be I updating this token often?

Then I guess I would just need to use [the flattr thing](http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/flattrs/#flattr-a-thing) api endpoint? Is a user considered a 'thing' in your api?  Is the `:id` for a `thing` secret or can it be public without harm?

Does a user know their id or can they easily find it?  Or would I need to use the [Users endpoint](http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/users/#get-a-user) to get that info? And does that mean adding an additional scope?

This is my ideal situation. In the chat all Users setup a flattr account and can connect the bot to Flattr by doing:
`!flattr addme [flattr username]` (alternatively they could use flattr ID if accessible)
then like I mentioned above, they can just use `!flattr @[username]` and that's it

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need API credentials but the ‘flattr’ scope should be enough.
You need to solve three problems, identifying users, authenticating users and then flattring URL:s (because the Flattr system only works with URL:s).

The later is easy, the best thing would be if your application/site provided a profile page for each user.
Something like ‘http://example.com/user/francisc0'. You would then just call the /flattr endpoint with that URL.
The response of the URL would either have to contain something that Flattr could use to ID the Flattr user or
you would have to pass the user id along with the flattr request. Read up on auto submit URL:s.
But in short, an auto-submit URL looks like
 https://flattr.com/submit/auto?fid=abc123&url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fuser%2Ffrancisc0

In order to identify your users they need to have unique usernames on the chat (or something else that is unique that you are able to lookup from a username). Each user would also have to tell your application what their flattr id is.
This can be as simple as a input field where the user manually adds their id or you could fetch it from the API (look at the /user endpoint).

Now in order to flattr an URL your application (api client) needs to be authenticated as a Flattr user. As the Flattr user that typed the command “!flattr @username”. So my suggestion is that when a user wants to enable the ability to flattr on the chat you perform an oauth authentication for them and save the access token (they never expire btw).
When the user types “!flattr @username” in the chat you retrieve the access token for that user from storage and then send the flattr request as that user.

That should be it.

I did something similar for IRC a few years back and it worked great so it should work for your use case too.

Pro tips: Avoid using the /thing endpoints as they will be deprecated very soon.
              The api documentation isn’t really up to date but that is also something that is changing very soon.
              The user objects will soon include an ‘idv3’ attribute, use that as the user id instead of ‘id’.

Source: am Flattr dev.